# Wordpress theme Modifications not showing up on live server

Tags: theme-development, customization, child-theme, cache, localhost

I have been working on localhost with a theme that was already installed on live server. After i completed my mods, uploaded the files to themes folder in wp-content but to my disappointment, the same old non-customized theme was showing up. Then I thought if I add my custom css codes to css editor then it will work fine but even after that nothing was showing up and I ended up with a totally messed up site. I tried to empty all the caches but still no luck. Before installing my custom theme, I actually deleted all the files associated with the old theme and then re-installed my own custom theme. 
For the sake of information, I am using Genesis Framework and I modified Genesis Sandbox HTML5 child theme. It works like a magic on my localhost but I don't know how to get it working.

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to update your database.
Before updating your database to the live server, you need to verify the URL.

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: Please add a good deal of explanation to your answer for users to have a good insight.